# My Database model is not showing in admin view

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-admin

admin view is not showing models.And yes, I am totally new to django. And I am totally new to this site.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

PUBLISH_CHOICES = (

    ('draft','Draft'),
    ('publish','Publish'),
    ('private','Private'),
)

app_name = 'Blog'

class Blog(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key = True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    body = models.CharField(max_length = 500, null = True)
    publish = models.CharField(max_length = 120, choices = PUBLISH_CHOICES, default = 'draft')
```

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'blog',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'



TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register you models in `admin.py` to view in Django admin.

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Blog

admin.site.register(Blog)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can very well use the decorator

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Blog

@admin.register(Blog)
```